# Wire identification for a camera system install

Tags: electrical, wiring, security

I am replacing some old cameras that came with the home to more modern ones.

I took apart 1 of the cameras to find this: [image]

Now I am guessing the yellow is video, and black and red are power (hot and neutral?)

I am not sure what the wire beside the yellow one is doing. I should add these were most likely installed by Brinks a long long time ago.

Here is another camera I want to replace:

[image]
[image]

Here the wire coming in has 5 wires? 1 video and 4 power? Hmm not sure what to make of that.

The cameras I bought are Lorex ones that use power and bnc cables:

[image]

I am guessing I have to cut that cable open and splice it in? Does anyone know if the supplied cable has three wires? two in the power part, and 1 in the BNC part?

The other end of the cable is a disaster. It must split somewhere and the video part goes into this:[image]

[image]

The power might go somewhere here:

[image]

But I'm not sure...

I also wanted to install a video doorbell where there used to be a working camera:

[image]
[image]
backside:
[image]

This camera has 3 lines into it: black red white. I am assuming two power and 1 video? Most likely DC power? From my understanding the nest and ring ones use AC power -- so this will probably not work?

Sorry for the long post, need some help! 
Thank you

Comment: Need a lot more info here. But first you need to clarify your question. If it's how to hook up your Lorex cameras you need to provide info on the cameras. The directions should tell you how to proceed. Did you follow them? What problems did you encounter? If you don't have the installation instructions look on-line for them. We'll try to help you to help yourself. Provide some additional info and edit your question to be clear on the current situation and what you're asking.

Comment: The camera system I got is the LX1080-44BW Lorex system. The current situation is how to hook up the cameras (I don't have them yet, they are shipping). I am doing preliminary research.

Comment: Have you thought about just upgrading the whole system, wires and all?  The cameras are usually the most expensive part .

Comment: Some cameras have another wire for the microphone.  Even if they don't have a microphone, the control board might have a pinout for one, and the wire that was run might have an extra wire to support it.

Comment: @JACK I really don't want to run new wire. If I can reuse the existing wire, then I think that is the way to go?

Comment: What the heck are all these components anyways? I can't find any info about the model numbers or anything. Think I should just go battery powered doorbell?

Answer (score 1):

"yellow" is probably the center conductor of the coaxial cable for video, the black one beside it is likely the shield/outer conductor and grounded. Hard to see for sure with a mess of black goop on there.

A BNC coax has **two** conductors - a center conductor and a circular shield conductor around the outside.

Red is likely **+** DC (12 or 24 volts most likely) black will be **-** DC and probably also ground in most (not all)  systems.

If the current system is not running coax (which it obviously has in the "video part" picture) all the way to the cameras you might need to run new coax. If it does, but without connectors, you might need to crimp new connectors onto the coax.

Comment: I agree that most of these cameras are low voltage looks like 12v because of the wall wart I see 12v. I would ask what kind of cameras all the newer ones I use do not use coax they cat 5+ or 6. To the dvr.

Comment: Post states that the new ones use power & BNC - not how I'd do it in the age of POE network cameras, but they are still made that way too.

Comment: I have adapters that break out video and power for some of my older cameras that I use POE. Much easier to work with than coax + power or power on the same coax as the video.

Comment: Well I picked the BNC / POWER combo instead of POE because the cables that are already in the home seem to be that. If I were to do it from scratch I would use POE.

Comment: Maybe I should get a cable tracer to see where that power breakout is. If it goes to that panel then I can just splice in the cable Lorex provides on both ends. Should work?

Comment: All the new cameras in the world will not produce anything close to a great picture on --much less be compatible with--  decades old wiring. I rarely advise people to throw stuff out, but this should be rewired with new "chinese cable" , cat 5e or 6...whatever Lorex recommends and the cameras are compatible with. The fittings on the cameras may dictate what type of wire is to be run. Look for books and web sites on structured or low voltage wiring. Or consult Lorex' web site and good luck. Wired my home for video, alarm and audio after training and studying..